# Androind ImageView in Fragment

Tags: android, imageview, fragment, android-volley

I am trying to put an image on my fragment, but the image is not showing up. I am certain that it was working just yesterday but now it is not. Any help is appreciated.

**This code is in my Fragment:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mUser = (User) getArguments().getSerializable(ARGS_USER);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_picture_picker, container, false);

    mImageView = v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    mSelectImageButton = v.findViewById(R.id.select_image);

    mSelectImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){


            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(intent, IMG_REQUEST);
        }
    });

    return v;

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if(requestCode == IMG_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null){
        Uri path = data.getData();

            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), path);
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mUser.setProfilePicture(bitmap);

            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Volley? You are just opening your File Manager to get your image on `onActivityResult`

Comment: Yes thank you, I was confused from a tutorial.  It seems like the following line is the problem:  bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), path);  Any way to get around it?

Comment: I have checked your code. Everything seems to be perfect.

Comment: Where you are testing your app? On emulator or physical device. Once try testing it on some different OS version or different device and revert what is happening.

Comment: I am testing it both on a Nexus 5 Emulator and my Samsung S6.  They are both not working.  Is something wrong with my ImageView?                            
       <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="79dp"
        android:layout_height="124dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="204dp" />

Comment: No problem with ImageView too. `Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + path.getPath());` in your `onActivityResult` and check whether your `onActivityResult` is executing or not.

Comment: Thank you, it seems like onActivityResult  is not executing.  What should I fix?

Comment: @VaradMondkar My problem was that I did not call super.onActivityResult() in my activity.  Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Yes, you have to call super.onActivityResult() in you activity. Great to known you got the solution. Happy coding brother :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are not using the Volley. Please change the heading of your question. You are accessing the Gallery and showing the image inside the imageView. Use the below code for accessing the image from camera as well as gallery.

```
if (action.equals("CAMERA")) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Check Permissions Now
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, ACTION_REQUEST_CAMERA);
        } else {
            openCamera();
        }

    } else if (action.equals("GALLERY")) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Check Permissions Now
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, ACTION_REQUEST_GALLERY);
        } else {
            openGallery();
        }
    }


private void openCamera(){
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    getActivity().startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, ACTION_REQUEST_CAMERA);
}

private void openGallery(){
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Choose a Picture");
    getActivity().startActivityForResult(chooser, ACTION_REQUEST_GALLERY);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    System.out.println("OnActivityResult");
    System.out.println("resultCode: "+resultCode+"\n"+"requestCode: "+requestCode);
    ImageOperations operations = new ImageOperations();
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == ACTION_REQUEST_GALLERY) {
            System.out.println("select file from gallery ");
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            renderProfileImage(selectedImageUri,operations);
        } else if (requestCode == ACTION_REQUEST_CAMERA) {

            System.out.println("select file from camera ");
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            String name = "profile_pic.png";
            operations.saveImageToInternalStorage(photo,getActivity(),name);
            profile_image.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }
}

private void renderProfileImage(Uri selectedImageUri,ImageOperations operations) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bytes);
        String name = "profile_pic.png";
        operations.saveImageToInternalStorage(bitmap,getActivity(),name);
        profile_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class ImageOperations {
    public boolean saveImageToInternalStorage(Bitmap image, Context context, String name) {

        try {
            // Use the compress method on the Bitmap object to write image to
            // the OutputStream
            FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("profile_pic.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            // Writing the bitmap to the output stream
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("saveToInternalStorage()", e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Bitmap getThumbnail(Context context,String filename) {

        String fullPath = Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        Bitmap thumbnail = null;

        // Look for the file on the external storage
        try {
            if (isSdReadable() == true) {
                thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fullPath + "/" + filename);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Image",e.getMessage());
        }

        // If no file on external storage, look in internal storage
        if (thumbnail == null) {
            try {
                File filePath = context.getFileStreamPath(filename);
                FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(filePath);
                thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fi);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("getThumbnail()", ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

        return thumbnail;
    }


    public boolean isSdReadable() {

        boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            // We can read and write the media
            mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
            Log.i("isSdReadable", "External storage card is readable.");
        } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
            // We can only read the media
            Log.i("isSdReadable", "External storage card is readable.");
            mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
        } else {
            // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other
            // states, but all we need to know is we can neither read nor write
            mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
        }

        return mExternalStorageAvailable;
    }
}
```

action is like what you want to do. ACTION_REQUEST_GALLERY and ACTION_REQUEST_CAMERA use some integer constants like 100 and 101. profileImage is your ImageView.

Comment: I am trying your code in a fragment but the image is not displaying.  The compiler warns that this line may return a Null Pointer Exception: bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);

Comment: Its just a warning. You can ignore it and proceed. It will work absolutely fine.